# Adding and substracting hours to a 24 hour time in python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, strftime, strptime

I need to subtract 5 hours from the string `"03:40"`

I've tried the following:

```
import datetime

timevar = "03:40"
newtime = datetime.datetime.date.strftime("%H:%M", timevar)
newtime = newtime - datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
print newtime
```

I've read the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) documentation but I still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help much appreciated.
- Hyflex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a few problems... First, you're looking for `strptime` and not `strftime`.  Second,  `strptime` is a method on `datetime.datetime`, not `datetime.datetime.date`.  Third, you've got the order of the arguments mixed up.  This should be what you want:

```
newtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timevar, "%H:%M")
newtime -= datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
```

*Note, this gives you a date portion that is somewhere around January 1st, 1900.  It seems like you only want the time portion, so that probably doesn't matter -- But I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Maybe OP would like to print `newtime.time()` instead of `newtime`.

Comment: @Hyperboreus -- Agreed.  or alternatively, *then* OP could use `strftime` to format the datetime however appropriate :).

Comment: @mgilson I'm now having issues actually turning it into `%H:%M` using `strftime`

Comment: @Hyflex -- It should just be `newtime.strftime('%H:%M')`.  The return value is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was desperate for some python lines that dealt with hours as string type.